# How to stop google chrome "Your payment" pop-up?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, woocommerce

I built a Woocommerce site. When I click "Proceed to checkout", the following chrome popup comes. But, it should go to my checkout page. It usually comes when I logged in my Gmail account, in another tab. Can anyone please tell me, how can I stop this pop-up coming! I want to go to my checkout page after clicking on "Proceed to checkout". It should not matter whether I am Gmail logged in or not

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people are having this kind of issue, but you can disable it quite easily.

Go to WooCommerce settings and look for something called "Payment Request API" (I don't know where exactly it is, but it is in the settings) - just disable it and the popup won't show anymore to you or anyone else logged in with their Google account.

[image]